# Lack of fermentation after racking to secondary

Tags: yeast, bottling, carbonation, secondary

After 3 weeks in fermenter, doppel bock went from O.G. 1.067 to 1.013, still bubbling occasionally, but not changing. However, after racking to secondary I see no fermentation  or bubbling and wonder if the remaining yeast will be viable enough to carbonate upon bottling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in my experience, there is still enough active yeast present for about 8 weeks.  Beyond that point then I would add just 1-2 grams of fresh yeast.  But you're not there yet so I'm sure it will turn out fine with no additional yeast.